# Ordered Dithering of image

Tags: image, image-processing, matrix

I did a lot of research and not able to find a simple way to understand the ordered dithering, particularly how different positions `M(i, j)` are calculated based on previous matrix. can somebody explain it on this matrix

```
1 2
3 4
```

Comment: Read this old blog post of mine: https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/355/

Comment: You could learn a great deal from Anthony Thyssen's pages here... https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#threshold